# Problems with connecting to wireless network on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, connection

I have a Dell laptop with Windows 7 (Home premium) 64 bit edition installed on it. I use a Wi-Fi router to browse the net. My problem is, I lose the network connection every 10 minutes or so. The network icon on the system tray shows the refresh icon and the status as "identifying network". The network is fine and works fine with my phone. I saw on the net this may be caused if I have enabled IPv6, so I disabled it but still problem persists. When I look at the event log I see the following entries: "Your computer was not assigned an address from the network (by the DHCP Server) for the Network Card with network address 0xXXXXXXXX.  The following error occurred: 0x79. Your computer will continue to try and obtain an address on its own from the network address (DHCP) server." I have also installed VirtualBox(32 bit edition) on the laptop. Does anybody any solution to this?

Comment: Which Dell laptop and wireless router are you using?

Comment: What happens when you assign a static IP address the laptop?

Comment: Have you tried with another router?

Answer (score 1):

### Try the following

1. Install the latest wireless network driver from Dells website and update the firmware on your router.
2. Reset your TCP/IP Stack using the following command:

   netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357